# How do you define a sample space with rigor?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was reading First Course on Probability by Sheldon Ross and I came across a problem which went like this:

 
"A customer visiting the suit department of a certain store will purchase a suit with probability $.22$,
a shirt with probability $.30$, and a tie with probability $.28$. The customer will purchase both a suit
and a shirt with probability $ .11$, both a suit and a
tie with probability $.14$, and both a shirt and a tie
with probability $.10$. A customer will purchase all $ 3$
items with probability $.06$. What is the probability
that a customer purchases
(a) none of these items?
(b) exactly $1$ of these items?"

 
Problem a) is easy to solve, what confuses me is part b). Ross solves it in the following way:

 The probability that two or more items are purchased is
$P(AB ∪ AC ∪ BC) = .11 + .14 + .10 − .06 − .06 − .06 + .06 = .23$
Hence, the probability that exactly $1$ item is purchased is $.51 − .23 = .28.$

Intuitively, I understand why he subtracts the probability of buying two or more things from the probability of buying anything at all. What I do not understand is the rigor behind it. Why am I justified in subtracting one probability from the other?

 
What I tried to do in order to justify this was saying $P( \mathrm {buying \ 2 \ or \ more \ things)} + P(\mathrm {buying \ 1 \ thing}) + P(\mathrm {buying \ nothing})=1$ since a customer must buy a shirt, or a tie, or a suit, or nothing, therefore the three terms above must add up to the probability of the sample space which equals one. 

A sample space is the set of all the outcomes of an experiment, the event space is a set of subsets of the sample space and an event is an element of the event space. I know that $P$ maps events to the unit interval, the only problem I have is how do I define the previous events (namely $\{ \mathrm {buying \ 2 \ or \ more \ things} \}$, $\{ \mathrm {buying \ 1 \ thing} \}$, $\{\mathrm {buying \ nothing}  \}$).

 
If I defined the sample space as $\{\mathrm {shirt, \ suit , \ tie , \ nothing} \}$, then the sets $\{ \mathrm {buying \ 2 \ or \ more \ things} \}$ and $\{ \mathrm {buying \ 1 \ thing} \}$ would not be disjoint and I would not be able to add them together like I did. So if I were asked to write those events explicitly, how would I go about doing it? Am I defining the sample space wrong? I need some clarification on exactly how to define sample spaces such that, if I wanted to, I could write them down explicitly.

Comment: The sample space here is presumably the power set of $\{\mathrm {shirt, \ suit , \ tie } \}$ and has $8$ possibilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT for clarity: Your logic is correct, the problem here is that an "event" can either mean *a singleton set* or **a set of singleton sets**.

So we have the probability space $\Omega = \{suit, hat, tie\}$, but the set of all events is the *power set* of $\Omega$, i.e. $\mathscr{P}(\Omega) = \{ \emptyset, \{hat\}, \{tie\}, \{suit\}, \{hat, tie\}, \{hat,suit\},\{tie,suit\} \{hat, tie,suit\} \}$.

The reasoning behind subtracting the probability is the *inclusion-exclusion principle*, for only two events it takes the form $\mathbb{P}(A \cup B) = \mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B) -\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)$, the subtraction of the intersection being in order to avoid double counting.

Also by the way Ross's book is excellent; the only book I would recommend for learning probability for the first time.

EDIT: an explicit example of the inclusion-exclusion principle:

Say we want to calculate the probability of buying a hat and a tie.

Then this event equals: $\{hat,tie\} \cup \{hat, tie,suit\}$, so to calculate the probability $\mathbb{P}(\{hat,tie\} \cup \{hat,tie,suit\} = \mathbb{P}(\{hat,tie\})+\mathbb{P}(\{hat,tie,suit\}) - \mathbb{P}(\{hat,tie\})$. This is because $\{hat,tie\} \subset \{hat,tie,suit\}$ i.e. $\{hat,tie\} \cup \{hat, tie,suit\}=\{hat,tie,suit\}$, so if we had included the probability of $\{hat,tie\}$ we would have been double-counting.

This isn't the best example admittedly; Feller vol. 1 or Shiryaev explain this better than I do.

Comment: But in the exclusion inclusion principle, what intersections and unions am I calculating?

Comment: Well it depends on what probability you want to calculate. I edited my answer to give an explicit example.

Comment: I fail to understand the phrase "an "event" can either mean a single set or a set of sets." Every event is a subset of Omega and the elements of Omega could be sets themselves in which case events would be sets of sets... But this fact is universally true, so why underline it as if it was crucial or explaining anything, especially since the examples you give afterwards are not of this nature?

Comment: In the discrete case it can be difficult conceptually to discern between the two possible interpretations of elementary events (either as points in the sample space i.e. elements of the sample space, or as singleton subsets of the sample space and thus equivalently an element of the power set). What appeared to be OP's conceptual problem was that they did not understand how to understand probabilities as defined on elements of the power set of the sample space, because they had been confused into thinking that probabilities were defined for elements of $\Omega$ and not of $\mathscr{P}(\Omega)$

Comment: It appears that the you are identifying the elementary event (buys) "nothing" with the empty set $\emptyset$, and that you are ok to include this very possible elementary event only in the sigma-algebra. Are you sure about this?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I don't think I understand your question. Elementary events are usually defined as points of the sample space, since buying nothing (i.e. the empty set) is not a point of the sample space, I do not see what the problem is. If one defines the sample space as above (the definition is arbitrary and there are many possible choices), I don't see how there is a problem. Also every element of the sigma algebra is "possible".

Comment: Well, "buying nothing" is not the empty set, because "buying nothing" is an elementary event (and so a point in the sample space), _given_ what the OP wants to model (if the situation was "assume that the customer will buy something with certainty", it would be different). By not including it in your $\Omega$, the resulting power set does not include events that contain "nothing" with strictly positive probability (since  the probability of the empty set is zero) while the situation the OP wants to model appears to allow (and possibly require) for a non-zero probability of "buying nothing".

Comment: That is a good point. I was not looking at the numerical probabilities, so I did not notice that "buying nothing" did not correspond canonically to the empty set. I hope my answer still resolves OP's confusion about the distinction between elementary events being considered both points in the sample space and also as singleton sets, i.e. as "events"/ points in the sigma algebra. If you prefer to edit the answer to add the event "buy nothing" as an elementary event, feel free to do so.

Comment: This would enrich the power set with many additional composite events -let's leave this as an exercise for the OP!

Comment: "the problem here is that an "event" can either mean a singleton set or a set of singleton sets." Again, this is awfully confusing. Are we supposed to understand that, for example, if Ω={suit,hat,tie} then {{suit},{hat}} is an event? If we are not (as I hope, since {{suit},{hat}} is **not** an event, at least when suit, hat, and tie are three different objects), what use is the sentence?

Comment: It is abuse of notation and it is awfully confusing, which is why OP had trouble with it, and which is why I used to have trouble with it. Nevertheless, I have found the distinction to not be emphasized, or weakly emphasized, by many of my professors and many of the textbooks which I have read. You are also correct that $\{ \{suit\},\{hat\} \}$ is not an event. The problem is that Ross refers to both the "point" $ hat  \in \Omega$ and the "set/event" $\{hat\}$ as "buying (only) a hat". This is what confused OP originally.

Comment: It is unfortunately not only probability theory where this abuse of notation occurs - consider how often $f^{-1}(x)$ is written when $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is meant.

Comment: Yes, if Ω={suit,hat,tie}, then hat is an element of Ω and {hat} is an event. No confusion there. The first sentence of the answer seems to *introduce* some confusion which was not in the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to model the number of items which are bought, your sample space could be the set of all tuples $(n_{\mathrm{shirt}},n_{\mathrm{suit}},n_{\mathrm{tie}})$, where the $n$'s are the number of each item bought (each one either $0$ or $1$ if we don't buy more than one of each).
Then, for example, the event
$$
\{\text{buying 1 thing}\}
= \{(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\},
$$
and the event
$$
\{\text{buying 2 things}\}
= \{(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)\}.
$$